# Trying to create a custom range slider in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a custom range slider component in Angular 4.
I do not want to use existing npm packages like NoUiSlider and also do not want to use jQuery.

The functionality is as follows.
The minimum value is 0.
The maximum value is 27.5.
The increments are 0.5.
The selected values can be anywhere within that range 0 - 27.5.
Can anyone show me how to create such a slider and bind the values?

Comment: Just to clarify, it needs to be a double slider so it can select a range

Answer (score -2):

If you want to create your own control then you need to implement ControlValueAccessor. Follow this article to create your own: https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2

Hope it will help